# SQL Cross Join Query not working with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, cross-join

This cross join works fine:

```
select * from x, y
```

I am trying to run this query:

```
select abc.col1 from abc
(select * from x, y) abc
```

But I get this error message:

```
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The column 'col1' was specified multiple times for 'abc'.
```

Both tables x and y have the same columns and column definitions.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select abc.col1 from abc
(select * from x, y) abc
```

You are aliasing two tables with the same name. Try:

```
select abc.col1 from abc,
(select x.* from x, y) abc2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to put `(select * from x, y)` as a variable `abc` and then use that variable in the select statement `select abc.col1 from abc`

Comment: Are there any columns in tables `x` and `y` that have the same name? If so, you will need to prefix with the table name such as `(select x.* from x, y)`. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify column name in inner query section.
something like this:

```
select abc.col1 from abc
(select x.col1,y.col1 from x, y) abc
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lock's answer, you also forgot the comma:

```
select 
    abc.col1 
from abc, (select * from x, y) abc2
```

Even better, using the ansi 1992 notation:

```
select 
    abc.col1 
from abc CROSS JOIN (select * from x, y) abc2
```